# Why does instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: not allocate more memory?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html), `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` "creates a new instance of the specified view controller each time you call it."

I'm running my app (using ARC) with Instruments' Activity Monitor, and I notice absolutely no difference in memory usage when I use to instantiate a ViewController that was instantiated before.

Why is that? See method `goToPreviousPage` below:

```
@implementation CBNavigator

int currentPage = 0;

-(IBAction)goToNextPage{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        currentPage++;
        UIViewController *nextPageVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentPage ]];
        [self presentModalViewController:nextPageVC animated:YES];
    }];        
}

-(IBAction)goToPreviousPage{    
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        currentPage--;
        UIViewController *previousPageVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentPage ]];
        [self presentModalViewController:previousPageVC animated:YES];
    }];
}
@end
```

Comment: Do you possibly already have a previous instance in memory? I.e, the new instance is replacing the old one, hence no bump in memory usage?